# MVC3 write to @rendersection more than once

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-partialview

How do I write to:

```
@RenderSection("Top", false)
```

more then one time from a partialview?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, directly.

Your content page could itself contain a `@RenderSection()` call, but I'm not sure that's what you mean.

Alternatively, if you want to write to different content areas, you can simply make multiple calls to `@RenderSection()`, and match the sections by name in your views.

Comment: I want to have my @rendersection in Layout and write to it, from a  partialview that is called more then once in the layout. Right now I can't even do it once from the partial view. So why can't you write to it directly? So what can you do with MVC3? just write to it from normal views?

Comment: You should just use `@Html.Partial()` for rendering partials in your view.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the partial View:

```
 @section Top{
       @: Hi from partial!  
 }
```

Inside the View:

```
 @section Top{
       @RenderSection("Top", false) 
 }
```

Inside Layout:

```
 @RenderSection("Top", false)
```

This is how you access the section from inside the partial view. You can't call it more than once though, and it doesn't make sense to have to write many times to it.

If you find that your partial view needs to write at "Top", then suddenly it needs to write at the "Bottom", you have a bad design and you need to rethink your views/controllers

Comment: @River copy and paste the snippet i have above, it should write "hi from partial!. Also note, that if the html container tag isn't visible, neither are the children tags

Comment: I can't write to it from the partial view..it seems i don't have reference to the layout from partial view(I return partial view from controller). More interesting on your second point. I just need my renditions of my partialview to write to the top part of the page, everytime it gets called in the layout. Can you write to rendersection multiple times from controller instead?

Comment: Ah, now I get it, you actually have 3 views. Updating the answer

Comment: I just want my partial view to write specific information to one place . If you can't write to an rendersection more than once, then how can I do that?